# Document is abstract; cannot be instantiated..to import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

Tags: itext

I know the solution is to import `com.itextpdf.text.Document` , But I couldnt find any jar file to import and fix the error.if any body knows the link for proper .jar file then please guide me . I am getting the following error -

> Document is abstract; cannot be instantiated..to import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the compiler error message? If it is "abstract class cannot be instantiated" (as in the title), you already have the jar file you need.

Comment: error: Document is abstract; cannot be instantiated
                Document document = new Document();error: cannot find symbol document.open();

Comment: Edit your question and put the additional information there. Not in a comment.

Comment: but still i cant import com.itextpdf.text.Document... any comments appreciate

Comment: Neither the `Document` of iText 5 nor of iText 7 is abstract. Probably you also import another class or interface named `Document` and so confuse the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1:**

The concept of a `Document` exists in many different contexts, for instance:

- `java.swing.text.Document`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html
- `org.w3c.dom.Document`: https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Document.html
- `com.itextpdf.text.Document`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html
- `com.itextpdf.layout.Document`: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/Document.html
- ...

Neither the `Document` class in iText 5, nor the `Document` class in iText 7 are abstract or an interface, hence the allegation *Document is abstract; cannot be instantiated* is false. It is safe to assume that you are using the wrong `Document` (but as you don't show us any case, we can't tell you which one you are using).

**Part 2:**

There are millions of developers using iText. They all downloaded the iText jar or imported it into their project using Maven:

- iText 7, see [download info](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-7) or [GitHub](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.0.1)
- iText 5, see [download info](http://developers.itextpdf.com/itext-java) or [GitHub](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/releases)

If you are using iText 7, we have several instruction videos on how to get started, depending on the IDE of your choice:

- [Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxArv-GskLc&)
- [NetBeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcOi99zW7O4)
- [IntelliJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WxITuCgpHQ)

All of these links can be found in the [Before we start: installing iText 7](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7) chapter of the [Jump-start tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial).

**Extra remark:** (borrowed from another Stack Overflow member)

[image]

Avoid writing things such as *I tried itext 5 and 7 from their site,but it doesn't work*, because:

- It **does work** for millions of other developers, and
- You insult the people who can help you by telling them their software is "bad".

Comment: thanks and appreciate you advice mate.. still iam new to this.sorry for inconvenience.